# Challenge: Position fixed in an iOS iframe

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, iframe, mobile-safari

So we all know that as of iOS 8.1.3 iframes render in their full length rather than being scrollable.

We can work around that with a wrapping div outside the iframe with style `height:Xpx; overflow-y:scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` which works really well, apart from fixed elements in the iframe appearing as absolutely positioned.

Solutions?

Bonus challenge: You have no control over the contents of the iframe, or what the fixed elements are / how many.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi @jannej, unfortunately not. The question remains open...

Comment: If you have the control over the content of the iframe; this could be your solution. https://github.com/PierBover/ios-iframe-fix